# geometry nodes and object instances not applying well to curved mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm having difficulty correctly applying object instances to a curved mesh object. You can see here from my image below that the instances are not curving with the curved mesh. I'd love some direction on how to do apply a flat object instance to a curved mesh and have it curved along the curved mesh face using geometry nodes. I have searched high and low on the interwebs and cannot seem to find an answer.

[image]

geometry nodes setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVF26.png

more example images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjWbB.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

here's a setup that could work for you... the plane you want to instantiate needs to have some resolution, just 4 vertices will not bend / adapt to mesh... and then you need to realize these instances to be able to move each vertex... a raycast node will search for best point on the surface to snap your vertices to

I used an icosphere to instantiate the planes -just a few- but then subdivided it to have a better surface for snapping... may need to flip the normals on the plane or the ray direction in raycast node... also remember that the grid or the sphere could even be GN primitives

[image: node setup]

Comment: That's fabulous!

Comment: thanks @NatureK you had a nice setup too, I saw later it was your answer linked here

Comment: No,I don't get the right answer,I just align the normal,but don't achieve the shrink.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to preserve the object that has the geometry node modifier? this seems to either remove its mesh or replace it with the object instances.

Comment: sure, use a 'join geometry' node next to the end and connect your 'group input' geometry... or place GN modifier on some other mesh and use 'info node' to input the sphere