# How to simulate spacecraft RCS thrusters animation?

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes, particle-nodes

I am creating photorealistic spacecraft animations and I would like to add reaction control system (RCS) thruster effects (see the linked video for a real world example). As I've never worked with Blender particle effects, ideally there might be a 3rd-party product or tutorial to get me started. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.10, Windows 11

[Real spacecraft RCS thrusters in operation](https://youtu.be/scGc1NS_IV8?t=208)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could fake it with a material on a cylinder: You need to mix an Emission with a *Transparent* node with a *Noise Texture* as factor, then mix with a *Transparent* with a *Layer Weight* as factor (to create a gradient on the width), then mix with a *Transparent* with a *Separate XYZ* as factor (to create a gradient on the length):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a great headlight to me…. +1 ….but…can you one time only do something for real and not just fake everything?!‼️

Comment: Actually I plan to build a reactor but I'm afraid it will take several days (plus Elon doesn't want to help me)

Comment: Yeah, because he has no time. But I help him with his projects so that he won‘t fail again.

Comment: Yes, I told him to hire you, I told him "Hey El', do you know this guy, Chris? This guy is really talented in Geometry Nodes, you should hire him", he told me "yes but I heard he was a bit lazy", I tried to convince him that you were not, glad he hired you after all

Comment: Yes, I know. Laziness is my second name. So I have to say „thank you moonboots, that you made me work for El, who made me a multibillionaire…thank you!

Comment: Hey man, glad I helped. By the way, Elon is still waiting for your help on his bowl project!! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256558/looking-for-a-way-to-evenly-space-objects-instances-across-mesh/256609?noredirect=1#comment438409_256609