# Modeling an organoid

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image: overall organoid shape]I am trying to model an organoid as shown in the attached image with the label "normal tissue organoids". I have started with a cube arrayed along a curve as in the attached .blend.
But I dont know how to reach the 3D form of the organoid as I cant array on a sphere?
The deformation of the cubes (cells) is crucial as it gives the organic look.

Thank you very much for your help[image]

[image]

Edit: I added a screenshot of how the overall organoid looks like. I need the shape to be lined with cubes as in the .blend file. Also, I need to show it as a cross section. The array in the blend file would be the rim of that cross-section.

Comment: it's not clear how is the back of the object you try to achieve, is it spherical?

Comment: I think the back could be either spherical or have extrusions like the ones that give rise to the star-like shape. Thank you!

Comment: you mean the back can look like the front?

Comment: The overall shape would be like a sea urchin: a ball that has extrusions to the sides. I need to show the shape as in the picture which is the organoid cut in half. Ideally I am looking for a model/object/array that has a sphere as basis and lets me adjust the shape as I need it without disturbing the cell layer. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot of the overall shape I am going for. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you need the non-intersection? For visualization, would something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/BV2L4Mx) do? (The cells intersect, but not visibly)

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi and thank you very much for your input! The intersection does not matter for the overall structure. It cannot be intersecting in the cross section though, but I could fix that by hand. Could you please share how you achieved this structure?

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks so much for your effort! The intersection in the cross section basically kills the look of the cells deforming in the curve (as in my blend file). Yet, this look is very common in biological illustrations and I woud like to try to get to it if possible at all.

Comment: @RobinBetts I'll also be keen to see what you bring up... To be honest, my answer was just an attempt at an answer, and I'm not that good in geo nodes (due to the fact I've been avoiding  them since they're released for stuff anything other than instancing plants or rocks)

Comment: Correction: simulation not needed. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try some variation on this approach:

Depending on your starting topology, the top 2 modifiers in ths stack are *Subdiv*, and *Decimate*. Balancing these two will yield a reasonably jumbled triangulation:

[image]

When the dual is taken of that geometry, the result is Voronoi-like.

After taking the dual, this GN group creates cells from it:

[image]

- It saves the vertex normals of the intact mesh, which will be needed later
- Then splits the faces and separates them by a fraction, so they won't be welded back together in a later move
- It extrudes the split faces along the saved vertex normals, so their sides remain parallel
- The top faces of the extrusion, and the original geometry faces, are both rounded out by extruding again, and scaling the top faces of the extrusion.
- The original is joined to the extrusion, and welded to it, completing the cells
- The result is Catmull-Clark subdivided in the GN modifier, with a heavy crease on the side-wall edges, so the cells don't separate:

[image]

Above is the result, seen from the outside.

The method seems to extend well enough to other organic solids, and it wouldn't be too many steps to a cutaway, although this one is very crude:

[image]

In the comments, illustrated with an inside/outside shader:

[image]

[image]

Variations on this method might be useful for crazy-paving, procedural stone-walling,corn-cobs, etc.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you very much for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through geometry nodes. Here's a try:

First, make the single instance object of what you want the cubes/cells to look like. Then, use this geo nodes setup to distribute them all over the surface:[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you very much! This looks promising, unfortunately I cannot read the node setup as it is very small in your image. Could you please post the nodes alone? Thank you!

Comment: No problem, attached @IamHidari

Comment: Hi, I tried it but I cant get the cubes to distribute evenly and without intersecting at high density. The goal is to achieve a structure as in the attached blend file, where each cube connects to the neighbouring one without intersecting. I am not very good at geo nodes unfortunately. Also, the cubes need to deform in places where there is a curve on the overall shape. Please see the organoid in the 2D illustration above. Thank you!

Comment: @IamHidari I've seen an answer here that does that, however, I don't remember it. Anyways, I'll check if I can do that and update my answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @IamHidari Check this out, maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256558/looking-for-a-way-to-evenly-space-objects-instances-across-mesh

Comment: @YousufChaudry Thank you very much! I will check it out.