# How to turn a trim sheet (plane) into an image that I can use to UV map the details (i.e., the geometry) onto faces of another object?

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-baking, geometry

I have taken a plane and modeled it into a pattern that I would like to be able to apply as a little detail, i.e., trim, to other objects. I have not applied any textures or materials to it; I simply want to be able to use UV mapping to copy the geometry from this plane onto faces of other objects and then bake it on. How can I make this plane appear in the UV editor?

I've seen a bunch of tutorials that involve exporting to Substance Painter, but I do not have it and I am not willing to spend any money to acquire it.

Comment: Copy an image of the geometry, or the geometry itself?   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/257987/35559 ?

Comment: Okay, yes, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If so, can we mark this question as a duplicate, then?

Comment: This does look like a duplicate. If not, you can edit, explaining the difference, and we can re-open.